# The best way to connect to database with Spring MVC

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have done some research but I haven't come to a final conclusion yet.

What is the best way to connect to MySQL DB when having Spring MVC + tomcat?

Is it Hibernate, JPA, JDBC or Hibernate/JPA?

Thanks,
Sara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) is more like a standard. [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is an implementation of the JPA, which means Hibernate is one possible way of using JPA for database connection.
Eclipselink is an other popular implementation of JPA. (Earlier versions of Hibernate was not JPA, but you'll probably do not want to use pre-JPA Hibernate.)

So these would be the options:

- Hibernate/JPA
- Eclipselink/JPA
- JDBC

[JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) is a low-level approach, it is much more troublesome to use it but also more felxible and sometimes you can achieve better performance with it. I'd drop JDBC until you have such problems that cannot be solved with JPA.

It is hard to choose between Hibernate and other JPA implementations unless you provide more details about your project. One thing is sure, Hibernate is popular (here on SO as well) and you'll be able to get help if you get stuck on a specific issue.

I suggest to go for Hibernate/JPA.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I'll go with Hibernate/JPA as you mentioned. I'll accept your answer later today.